# Trigger to capture attachment url to record detail page

Tags: apex, custom-field

I am capturing image from webcam and storing the image in record attachment by a managed package app. I have a text field in record detail page path__C where i need to capture inserted image (in attachment)  path url. Can anyone help me in that.

I have tried writing down the trigger. I need a small help in this. Below is my trigger . In this i want to filter out those attachments whose name is 'Default.png' and then update. Please help.

```
trigger SetIdToAttachment on Attachment (after insert) {
String Title;
Id pId;

for(Attachment att: trigger.new){
Title=att.Id;
pId=att.ParentId;
}

List<Devotee_Details__c> c=[select Id , GnD__c from Devotee_Details__c where Id=:pId];

//assuming one record is fetched.
c[0].GnD__c=Title;

update c[0];

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i need to capture inserted image (in attachment) path url"? Do you want a URL to view the attachment you just created?

Comment: I need that url into a custom field of the detail record..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Add snapshot to a custom object record from webcam](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82953/how-to-add-snapshot-to-a-custom-object-record-from-webcam)

Comment: No Eric..tht part I covered it with a AppExchange app. After the image is captured I want the url of the attachment in a custom field of the record.

Answer (score 1):

The URL to view the attachment will be something like:

https://c.na5.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P7000000iz5LF

You will need to swap out the na5 instance for your current pod identifier. The attachment Id will also need to be changed from `00P7000000iz5LF`

If you want to use a Forumla to display the attachment image, consider using the IMAGE function. See [Sample Image Link Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm&language=en_US)